# TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable") EncodeError: array [...] dtype=float32) is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, serialization, pyspark

**Background:** I have been working with [distributed-deep-q-project](https://github.com/kjchavez/distributed-deep-q) for 2 weeks and im very close to end. I got at last game visualizing working but when i'm trying to train a model with deep-q-learning with command (Readme with spark)

`./spark-submit --master local[*] --files models/deepq/train_val.prototxt,models/deepq/solver.prototxt,models/deepq/deepq16.caffemodel --py-files barista.zip,gamesim.zip,expgain.py,replay.py,main.py ddq.py`

program iterates 500 steps correctly but after that it is trying to save snapshot and fails with error:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
>       raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
>   EncodeError: array([[[[  1.09661017e-02,   3.62367812e-03,   8.45646951e-03,(very much numbers in arrays) 
>    dtype=float32) is not JSON serializable

I have been stucked for a while and if someone have even a clue I will be happy to see it. The error message was much longer and I will send it if you ask so. Code for project can been found in github from hyperlink above. Im using Ubuntu16.04 and python2.7.

Comment: the issue seems to be simply that your `array` is not JSON serializable. You need to ensure it can be converted to JSON, perhaps by extending `json.JSONEncoder` https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder

Comment: Al I have found useful this post (for arrays problems / serialization): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809410/7127519